# Getting zipcode from a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get zipcodes out of address strings.

Zipcodes may look like this: `23-123` or `50-530`.

Strings usually look like this: `Street 50, 50-123 City`

What I tried to do is finding the position of the zipcode and cut the next 6 characters starting from that point. Unfortunatelly strpos returns false all the time.

```
$zipCodePosition = strpos($form->address, "\d{2}-\d{3}");
$zipCode = $zipCodePosition ? substr($form->address, $zipCodePosition , 6) : '';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strpos` does not allow the use of regex as an argument.

You need a `preg_match` / `preg_match_all` here:

```php
// Get the first match
if (preg_match('~\b\d{2}-\d{3}\b~', $text, $match)) {
   echo $match[0];
}

// Get all matches
if (preg_match_all('~\b\d{2}-\d{3}\b~', $text, $matches)) {
   print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

The regex matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `\b` - a word boundary

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ULKPKq/1).